# printf causes crash

Tags: c++, c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(char sendbuf[100]) 
{
  printf (sendbuf);
  return 0;
}
```

Somehow this very basic program crashes when I try to use it, it's meant to print up whatever is typed as a parameter. If I remove the line "printf (sendbuf);" the crash goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Your first parameter must be an integer, not a char array.  Here is the right program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        printf( argv[1] );
    }
    else { 
        printf( "No arguments provided" );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

argv[0] is your program name, so argv[1] is the first parameter provided on teh command line.

Comment: program.exe 'No arguments provided'

Comment: @JiveDadson: Yep.  I originally skipped parameter checking to keep the example as simple as possible.  Anyway, someone else modified the answer, and I adjusted it a bit, so that's addressed.

Answer (score 1):

C supports two forms of main function:

```
int main() { /* ... */ }
and
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

To take parameter from main, you need to change your code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{    
  if (argc > 1){
    printf ("%s\n", argv[0]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Or use stream:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{    
   if (argc > 1){
     std::cout << argv[0]) << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

argv[0] is application name, input parameters starts from argv[1] if any.

Comment: Why C++? The question is tagged C.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `main` is the number of parameters. The second argument is an array of strings. The first element (index 0) of the second argument is the name of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int c, char **argv) 
{
  printf ("%s\n", c > 1 ? argv[1] : "No Argument");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: My test-case is "program.exe 'No Argument'".

Answer (score 0):

An implementation must support the following two definitions of `main`:

```
int main() { }
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { }
```

It is implementation-defined whether they support any other definitions. I don't know of any implementation that allows `int main(char*)` though (which is what yours is equivalent to).

Answer (score 0):

This will print everything you type on the command line after the program name, even with spaces. It will not crash if you type nothing after the program name.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    for(int i=1; i<=argc; ++i) { 
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
}
```